# Trying to implement Maxmind downloadable database with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, location, maxmind

I am trying to implement Maxmind downloadable databases within a WordPress theme form where I want to detect and print visitor's country automatically.

I followed this tutorial: http://slicejack.com/implementing-geoip-functionality-wordpress-theme/ and did all  the steps. But as I try to print the county as so `<h4><?php echo $geoip2_country_code; ?></h4>` It's doing nothing. I don't know what am I doing wrong, any help would be great.

Comment: Where *exactly* does your code not work? Did you try to debug the return values `get_geoip2_reader`? Did you ensure that you do not access with a private IP address, but a public IPv4?

Comment: I am not much experienced with this, so I am not sure if I can explain well. I wanted to test if maxmind is working by printing the country name fetched using the $geoip2_country_code;. And as I said I am not sure what I am doing wrong given my lack of expertise.

Comment: And I am not using a private IP as I tried other services as well which returned my location and everything perfectly. But for this I have to use Maxmind, which seem to go over my head no matter how much I read the documentation.

Comment: If you followed the tutorial exactly, then there is probably something wrong with your setup. But unless you give more information on your setup, it is unlikely that you get useful answers. Also, as I said in my first comment, you should first debug the code yourself (examine actual function calls, parameters, return values—do they make sense?), then *share your research*. Please also read and familiarise yourself with [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).